# How can I tie two combo boxes together in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I have 2 combo boxes, one that contains a list of 'Items' and another that contains a list of 'Subitems'.

The list of Subitems depends on the currently selected Item.

I've got most of this working (by binding the ItemSource of the Subitems to a PossibleSubitems property), however the problem is when I change the Item and the Subitem is no longer valid for the new item. In this case I just want to pick the first valid subitem, but instead I get a blank combo-box. Note that I think that the property in the class is set correctly, but the binding doesn't seem to reflect it correctly.

Here's some code to show you what I'm doing. In this case, I have:
'Item 1' which can have SubItem A or Subitem B and
'Item 2' which can have SubItem B or Subitem C

The problem comes when I switch to Item 2 when I have Subitem A selected.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="134" Width="136">
  <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleItems, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleSubitems, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding CurrentSubitem}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    // List of potential Items, used to populate the options for the Items combo box
    public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleItems
    {
      get
      {
        ObservableCollection<string> retVal = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        retVal.Add("Item 1");
        retVal.Add("Item 2");
        return retVal;
      }
    }

    // List of potential Items, used to populate the options for the Subitems combo box
    public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleSubitems
    {
      get
      {
        ObservableCollection<string> retVal = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        if (CurrentItem == PossibleItems[0])
        {
          retVal.Add("Subitem A");
          retVal.Add("Subitem B");
        }
        else
        {
          retVal.Add("Subitem B");
          retVal.Add("Subitem C");
        }
        return retVal;
      }
    }

    // Track the selected Item
    private string _currentItem;
    public string CurrentItem
    {
      get { return _currentItem; }
      set
      {
        _currentItem = value;
        // Changing the item changes the possible sub items
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PossibleSubitems");
      }
    }

    // Track the selected Subitem
    private string _currentSubitem;
    public string CurrentSubitem
    {
      get { return _currentSubitem; }
      set
      {
        if (PossibleSubitems.Contains(value))
        {
          _currentSubitem = value;
        }
        else
        {
          _currentSubitem = PossibleSubitems[0];
          // We're not using the valuie specified, so notify that we have in fact changed
          NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentSubitem");
        }
      }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.DataContext = this;
      CurrentItem = PossibleItems[0];
      CurrentSubitem = PossibleSubitems[0];
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote my own sample - kept it code behind so as not to deviate from your sample too much. Also, I'm using .NET 4.5 so didn't have to provide property names in OnPropertyChanged calls - you will need to insert them if on .NET 4.0. This works in all scenarios.

In practice, I'd recommend locating this code in a view-model as per the MVVM pattern. Aside from the binding of the DataContext, It wouldn't look too different from this implemenation though.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _currentItem;
        private string _currentSubitem;
        private ObservableCollection<string> _possibleItems;
        private ObservableCollection<string> _possibleSubitems;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadPossibleItems();
            CurrentItem = PossibleItems[0];

            UpdatePossibleSubItems();

            DataContext = this;
            CurrentItem = PossibleItems[0];
            CurrentSubitem = PossibleSubitems[0];

            PropertyChanged += (s, o) =>
                {
                    if (o.PropertyName != "CurrentItem") return;
                    UpdatePossibleSubItems();
                    ValidateCurrentSubItem();
                };
        }

        private void ValidateCurrentSubItem()
        {
            if (!PossibleSubitems.Contains(CurrentSubitem))
            {
                CurrentSubitem = PossibleSubitems[0];
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleItems
        {
            get { return _possibleItems; }
            private set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _possibleItems)) return;
                _possibleItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleSubitems
        {
            get { return _possibleSubitems; }
            private set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _possibleSubitems)) return;
                _possibleSubitems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string CurrentItem
        {
            get { return _currentItem; }
            private set
            {
                if (value == _currentItem) return;
                _currentItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string CurrentSubitem
        {
            get { return _currentSubitem; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _currentSubitem) return;
                _currentSubitem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void LoadPossibleItems()
        {
            PossibleItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
                {
                    "Item 1",
                    "Item 2"
                };
        }

        private void UpdatePossibleSubItems()
        {
            if (CurrentItem == PossibleItems[0])
            {
                PossibleSubitems = new ObservableCollection<string>
                    {
                        "Subitem A",
                        "Subitem B"
                    };
            }

            else if (CurrentItem == PossibleItems[1])
            {
                PossibleSubitems = new ObservableCollection<string>
                    {
                        "Subitem B",
                        "Subitem C"
                    };
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with other posters comments about adopting an MVVM approach. The key here though is that you need to model the coersion explicitly rather than hacking around it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure he'll need to if he does it the right way ... I'm sure the INPC will take care of that ...

Comment: You can do it with INPC, but it's inefficient, and can blow up once with more complex models where precidence matters. I've tied myself in knots in the past not doing it explicitly. I think it's better to be explicit from the outset. YMMV...

Comment: That code is awful (the code behind, not yours)... yeah, It can be hacked, but it'll be so much better to do it properly, this way he can extend it as well ...

Comment: It's better, though switching back to Item 1 from Item 2 (when subitem C is selected) doesn't work, but stepping through the code it's following exactly the same code path! This, combined with the comments it making me think that I'm going a bit off piste here. I think I need to go back and read some more MVVM stuff....

Comment: The key point is to leverage INPC so that the dependents of a property react to a change that can render them invalid. That involves proactively subscribing to the dependent property change event in your VM. Relying on the view to call the setter of the dependent isn't a great idea. That's why I advise wiring up an event handler rather than abusing the dependent's getter. Getters shouldn't have side effects, like my hack does above!

Comment: Couldn't live with the ugly code... edited in a cleaned up version.

Comment: Hehe, fair enough. Given all the comments on this I've stepped back a bit and stared implementing a ViewModel for my underlying class - if only as a learning experience! I'll mark this as a solution, but do you want to put a bit at the top about 'Maybe don't do it this way' - for any future visitors?

Answer (score 1):

You're notifying the wrong property. On your `CurrentItem`, you call the `"PossibleSubitems"`.

```
private string _currentItem;
public string CurrentItem
{
  get { return _currentItem; }
  set
  {
    _currentItem = value;
    // Changing the item changes the possible sub items
    NotifyPropertyChanged("PossibleSubitems");
  }
}
```

Fix that and try again :)

---

**WARNING ... THIS IS A HACK ...**
I changed this to make it work (just because I was curious), but this is by no mean the **proper** way, nor an elegant one:

```
// List of potential Items, used to populate the options for the Subitems combo box
public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleSubitems { get; set; }

// Track the selected Item
private string _currentItem;
public string CurrentItem
{
    get { return _currentItem; }
    set
    {
        _currentItem = value;
        // Changing the item changes the possible sub items
        if (value == "Item 1")
        PossibleSubitems = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"A","B"} ;
        else
        PossibleSubitems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "C", "D" };


        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        RaisePropertyChanged("PossibleSubitems");
    }
}
```

So basically, when current item change, it'll create new collection of subitems ...
UGLY !!! I know ... You could reuse those collections, and do lots of other things ... but as I said, I was curious about if it can be done this way ... :)

**If this breaks your keyboard, or your cat runs away, I TAKE NO RESPONSIBILITY WHATSOEVER.**

Comment: But when I change the Item, it's the possible sub items that change (granted I should probably notify that CurrentItem has changed also). If I don't notify about PossibleSubItems, then the SubItems combo box doesn't update at all and shows an entirely incorrect value rather than being blank

Comment: Well ... you changed the CurrentItem ... the thing is, I'm rather unhappy with your implementation ... I would go with some MVVM (not code behind), and have 2 different subitems lists (you can still do that). Have the subitems collection bind to the correct one, and when you change your CurrentItem, you can do something like `PossibleItems = this_or_that_collection`. Then it'll change, and the INPC property will fire on that as well, and the gui will change

Comment: Darnit ... i should have put it in the answer and used them 10 rep points for something .... :)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm afraid couldn't get your code to work. I get the theory, but in practice it just leaves me with a blank Subitems checkbox when I switch the Item.